# Instanciar uma classe a partir do nome dela em string

Tags: c#

Tenho um select onde tenho algumas opções

- Teste1
- Teste2
- Teste3

Tenho um model para cada opção

```
public class Teste1() {
//atributos e métodos
}
```

Gostaria de em determinada parte do meu sistema, receber essa string ex: "Teste1"

e criar um objeto do tipo Teste1

algo como:

```
var objeto = new "Teste1"
```

Ou seja gerar um objeto a partir de seu nome

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa disto? Em geral não precisa, tem mecanismos muito melhores. Eu poderia indicar algo se conhecesse o problema que está querendo resolver. Isto já costuma ser gambiarra em linguagem dinâmica, pior ainda em linguagem estática. Muitas vezes é feito para economizar alguma digitação e isto não é adequado. Complicaria a aplicação sem ganho. Pelo contrário.

Comment: Claro por favor, o problema e que eu terei um metodo isValid em cada model, teste1, teste2

e em um controller eu preciso receber la da view qual cara eu to querendo validar, porem na minha view eu so tenho como passar o nome da classe pois ira vir a partir da escolha do usuário la na tela, entao eu apenas me preocuparia em criar a instancia a partir da escolha dele, e chamar o isValid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito usando `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Geralmente não existe necessidade real de se trabalhar com isso, então é bom analisar bem o problema e repensar sobre o uso deste mecanismo.

O código seria assim:

```
var objeto = Activator.CreateInstance("Assembly", "Teste1");
```

Onde `Assembly` é o nome do *assembly* onde a classe se encontra. É possível usar `null` se o *assembly* for o que está sendo executado.

Comment: cara estou passando o assembly (pelo menos acho que estou) e me estoura um erro qeu o arquivo nao foi encontrado, mas no caso ele esta em outro projeto na mesma solução

o caminho da classe que eu quero instanciar esta em ProjetoDomain.Models.TesteDomain

entao estou passando assim

``var objeto = Activator.CreateInstance("ProjetoDomain.Models.TesteDomain", "Teste1");``

Comment: Resolvido assim(utilizando seu exemplo): 

string type = "Model";


var x = Assembly.Load("Assembly").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == type);
 var y =  Activator.CreateInstance(x);
 y.GetType().GetMethod("Method").Invoke(y, null);